# Query builder for InfluxDB?

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python

What is the preferred way of properly building InfluxDB queries in Python?

(I have been looking for a proper InfluxDB query builder. The ones I've found are either old/outdated or can't really generate valid queries for InfluxDB.)

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use [Pinform](https://github.com/sinarezaei/pinform) which is some kind of ORM/OSTM (Object time series mapping) for InfluxDB.

It can help with designing the schema and building normal or aggregation queries.

```
cli.get_fields_as_series(OHLC,
    field_aggregations={'close': [AggregationMode.MEAN]},
    tags={'symbol': 'AAPL'},
    group_by_time_interval='10d')
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library